# iOS UITesting with XCTest & Xcode - testing dynamically added elements

Tags: xcode, swift, xctest, xcode-ui-testing, xcode7.3

I have a tableViewCell with two switches. One is always present, the other is hidden and only appears when I set my UIPicker to a specific value.

In my test case I set the UIPicker to the necessary value as follows:

```
var app = XCUIApplication()
let tablesQuery = app.tables
   tablesQuery.cells.childrenMatchingType(.TextField).elementBoundByIndex(1).tap()

app.pickerWheels["Value 1"].tap()
app.pickerWheels["Value 1"].adjustToPickerWheelValue("Value 2")
app.toolbars.buttons["Done"].tap()
```

Looking at the simulator, the second switch appears as needed. However, it is nowhere to be found in `app.switches`.

I tried to reload the XCUIApplication as such:

```
app = XCUIApplication()
```

But in the debugger, when I printed out app.switches, the second switch wasn't there. I set the identifier for it in the Interface Builder, but still nothing. The following doesn't work:

```
        let current401kToggle = app.switches.elementMatchingType(.Switch, identifier: "Value2Toggle")
```

Any help appreciated :)
Thanks!

Comment: Once the switch appears, can Accessibility Inspector.app see it?

Comment: @JoeMasilotti I'd never heard of that before. Researching now and will let you know when I figure it out. Thanks!